# Bootstrap CSS - How to get control label with inline radios below it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my form I have two cols with the label on top and a full width input. My problem is that I now have two fields requiring radios. I want to split the col into 2 and have the two labels with their two radios below. I can get that ok but the alignment is then not right on the next field down.

You can see it here in this bootply http://www.bootply.com/VlFHq0daui

Leased property and mesne rate units. The key codes below it is not aligning correctly.

[image]

```
<form>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address_line1" class="control-label">Address 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_line1">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address_line1" class="control-label">Address 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_line2">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="town" class="control-label">Town*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="town">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="county" class="control-label">County</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="county">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eircode" class="control-label">Eircode</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eircode">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="reference" class="control-label">Reference</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reference">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tax_reference" class="control-label">Tax Reference</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tax_reference">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="local_authority" class="control-label">Local Authority</label>
            <select name="local_authority" id="local_authority" class="form-control">
                <option>Select...</option>
                <option value="41">Ahtlone Town Council</option>
                <option value="88">Youghal Town Council</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <label for="leased_property" class="control-label">Leased Property?</label>
                    <br>

                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="leased_property" id="leased_property" value="YES"> Yes
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="leased_property" id="leased_property" value="NO"> No
                    </label>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <label for="mesne_rates_unit" class="control-label">Mesne Rates Unit?</label>
                    <br>

                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="mesne_rates_unit" id="mesne_rates_unit" value="YES"> Yes
                    </label>

                    <label class="radio-inline">
                      <input type="radio" name="mesne_rates_unit" id="mesne_rates_unit" value="NO"> No
                    </label>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="key_code" class="control-label">Key Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="key_code">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gprn_number" class="control-label">GPRN Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gprn_number">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mprn_number" class="control-label">MPRN Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mprn_number">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant code into the question itself.

Comment: The code is in the Bootply. You'll get a visual along with the code there and you can use Bootply to edit the code to see if you know how to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but Bootply is blocked at my work, so this question is meaningless for me. It'd also be meaningless for anyone else who is unable to access Bootply (if it goes down, for instance).

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Ok got the code in and added an image too so you can see what is happening. Ideally I shouldn't be using a br tag between the labels and the radios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can warp radios inputs inside a div with same height of input box:

```
<div class="radios">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="leased_property" id="leased_property" value="YES"> Yes
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="leased_property" id="leased_property" value="NO"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.radios{

    height: 34px;
    padding: 5px;

}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/FEsPspjDlC)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking and it doesn't seem possible with just the native bootstrap framework on its own does it?

Comment: Yes i think that, but at the moment we can move around solution with some tricks until we have a pure bootstrap framework possibility, _Thanks_.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.form-group {
    min-height:59px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trying I found a solution, its not perfect, but will solve the issue.
You could wrap your radio elements into a `row` and hardcode the needed margins to align the buttons the way you want. For this I gave the `row` a custom class `align-radios`.

HTML:

```
<div class="row align-radios">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="leased_property" id="leased_property" value="YES"> Yes
    </label>

    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="leased_property" id="leased_property" value="NO"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.align-radios {
    margin: 7px 0 7px 5px; 
}
```

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking and it doesn't seem possible with just the native bootstrap framework on its own does it?

Comment: I dont think that these are the perfect solutions, I think too there must be a better solution, which is more dynamic. But for the moment you have at least somthing you can work with! And due to the fact the nobody answered I thought this could be a way to go.